# Table row beside each other

Tags: php, html, html-table, row

I tried to allow the last `td` in this code to be beside the previous `td`, but I can't and the `td` is printed in a new line. How to allow them to be beside each other,the problem is that the 1st 5 `td` are in a foreach loop and the last `td` is not follow this foreach as it's value is a function and not a key or a value in the foreach.

```
<?php foreach($downloads as $dl) { ?>
<tr id="this">
 <td ><img src="images/<?=$dl['type']?>.png"/></td> 
 <td id="no3"><?=$dl['type']?></td>
 <td>
  <a target="_blank" style="margin-right:3px" href="download.php?id=<?=$dl['id']?>">
   <?=$dl['title']?>
  </a>
 </td>
 <td>
  <center>
   <a href="http://<?=urlencode($dl['surl'])?>"><?=$dl['sname']?></a>
  </center>
 </td>
 <td align="center"><?=$dl['views']?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>


  <td  align="center"><?=$core->use_love(); ?></td>
```

[image: http://advphp.com/imgup/images/41553286204776144664.jpg]
[image: http://advphp.com/imgup/images/86639621977227017216.jpg]

The function of the last td

```
    public function use_love(){

    $sql=mysql_query("select * from wcddl_downloads ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$this->pg.",".$this->limit."");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
    $down_id=$row['id'];
    $love=$row['love'];
    ?>
    <div class="box" align="center">
    <a href="#" class="love" id="<?php echo $down_id; ?>">
    <span class="on_img" align="left"> <?php echo $love; ?> </span> 
    </a>
    </div>
    <?
    }               
 }
```

Comment: You can still place it in the for each loop, it will still run and add the value to the last row. Or you can run the function outside the loop, store it's value and insert the value into the td (which again will be inside the for each loop).

Comment: i don't want the function to be inside the foreach loop, as it will be iterated in a single td,i just want the way to make 2 tr beside each other provided that the td of function is outside the loop

Comment: Are you wanting that final column to be displayed on every single row, or just the last row?  Why can't you store it in a string and add it inside the foreach as `@Davos555` has suggested?

Comment: Perhaps you could draw a diagram and upload to help explain?

Comment: yeh, i want the column of the last td to be printed inside each tr of the foreach loop,but i don't want to be apart of the loop,as the function of this td contain a while loop ,which loop independently of the foreach loop

Comment: Still not quite sure what you're trying to do, but my answer doesn't make any sense with your diagram now. You may want to reformulate the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last `<td>` (the one outside the `foreach` loop) is on a new line because it's outside the last `<tr>` tag. One way to solve this is to always close the `</tr>` tag after the last `<td>`, like this:

```
<?php
$first_time = True;
foreach($downloads as $dl) {
    // If this is the first time through the loop, don't echo a </tr> tag:
    if ($first_time) {
        $first_time = False;
    } else {
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    // Now print the new row, but don't close it yet:
?>

<tr id="this">
  <td><img src="images/<?=$dl['type']?>.png"/></td> 
  <td id="no3"><?=$dl['type']?></td>
  <td><a target="_blank" style="margin-right:3px" href="download.php?id=<?=$dl['id']?>"><?=$dl['title']?></a></td>
  <td><center><a href="http://<?=urlencode($dl['surl'])?>"><?=$dl['sname']?></a></center></td>
  <td align="center"><?=$dl['views']?></td>

<?php
}
?>

<td align="center"><?=$core->use_love(); ?></td> 
</tr>
```

This will always put the last `<td>` in the final row.

Comment: I think you would also need a `colspan="2"` attribute in your `<TD>` where you display the views except for the last one. To get the last download, you need a `count($downloads)`, increment it each time you loop and check it accordingly to insert the last `<TD>`.

Comment: good idea steve,but the last td is printed in a new line,but in the same position of what i want,just we want the way to be in the same line ........

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE: I just saw you added a diagram.  This answer now makes no sense as the text description given earlier has nothing to do with what you want to achieve in the diagram.**

I submit the modification to Steve Nay's answer as you need the same number of `TD` in all your `TR`.  When you don't have the same count, you need to use `colspan` to achieve it.  I've added a counter to check if it's the last time you loop.  Here it goes:

```
<?php
$downloads_count = count($downloads);
$counter = 0;
foreach($downloads as $dl) :
  $counter++;
  // If this is the first time through the loop, don't echo a </tr> tag:
  if ($counter > 1) {
      echo "</tr>";
  }

  // Now print the new row, but don't close it yet:
?>

<tr id="this">
  <td><img src="images/<?=$dl['type']?>.png"/></td> 
  <td id="no3"><?=$dl['type']?></td>
  <td><a target="_blank" style="margin-right:3px" href="download.php?id=<?=$dl['id']?>"><?=$dl['title']?></a></td>
  <td><center><a href="http://<?=urlencode($dl['surl'])?>"><?=$dl['sname']?></a></center></td>
  <td align="center"<?php if ($downloads_count != $counter) echo ' colspan="2"'; ?>><?=$dl['views']?></td>

<?php endforeach; ?>

  <td align="center"><?=$core->use_love(); ?></td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: thanks maxiem,i hope if reached what i want,in brief to  describe more,
this is the code of the function in the last td